# build.spark: add spark dependencies

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I was trying to download spark-core and spark-sql in the build.sbt file:

```
name := "spark Test App"
version := "0.1"
organization := "sura.organization"
scalaVersion :=  "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion := "2.3.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion)
```

When I was running sbt package, I was getting an error as

/build.sbt]:7: '=' expected.

I was not able to find the error, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
val sparkVersion := "2.3.1"
```

It should be

```
val sparkVersion = "2.3.1"
```

Also, you should mark these depenedencies as **Provided**, because you only need them for compile and local execution *(e.g. tests)*. But in production you will deploy your jar to an Spark cluster, which *(obviously)* already includes them.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided
)
```

**PS:** Make sure you use the same Spark and Scala versions as your deploy cluster.

BTW, If you need to include other dependencies *(e.g. the Mongo Spark connector)* you should take a look at [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), but be aware that you will need to exclude the Scala standard library from the assembly jar.